# Automatic picture size adjustment

Tags: automation, graphics

Does anyone know of a *free* Windows utility that allows you to paste into it a graphics file (any type would work for me, jpg, bmp, png, etc) and it will size the file to within a preset size boundary?

For instance, if I preset it to resize files to be a maximum of 400 wide by 300 tall, and I paste in a file 500x500, it would shrink the file to fit within the 300 tall limit.

Thanks.

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: For Windows.  I added that bit into the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do such things using GIMP, but it is some clicks away. If you like a command line tool, imagemagick will gladely do it for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked out ImageMagick and found out how to do it.  Looks like I can write a little dos script that will automate a lot of it.  I'm still hoping for super fast (and free) drag-and-drop option, but ImageMagick is far better than doing it manually, as I have been.  Thanks again.